# Skype audio not working in 16.04

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

OS: Kubuntu 16.04

Desktop Environment:KDE 5.6.4

Issue: Skype microphone not working

Skype settings screenshot:
[image]

PulseAudio Screen screenshot:

[image]

Packages installed:

```
abhishek  $ dpkg -l |grep pulse
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                   1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64                   1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                                 1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulse0:i386                                  1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    i386         PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                               1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
ii  pulseaudio                                      1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-equalizer                            2.7.0.2-5~webupd8~xenial0                         all          PulseAudio Equalizer - LADSPA plugin graphical user interface
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                           1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                                1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                    amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
abhishek  $ dpkg -l |grep alsa
ii  alsa-base                                       1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                              all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                      1.1.0-0ubuntu5                                    amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                         1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

I have tried numerous solutions online, installing various packages but none has worked.

Other things to note:
I hear audio in skype.

Comment: Did you try unmuting the mic from that last window?

Comment: @dadexix86 how do you know it is muted?

Comment: There is a red line next to the symbol of the speaker. This means either that it is muted or that it is not properly recognised (with the result that it is muted). You try to unmute it, if it doesn't work than the problem is that it is not recognised.

Comment: It is a button, when I press it gets mute(, atleast that is what it says.) I think it is latter you said. It is not recongised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting in Pulse Audio Volume Control:

Open Pulse `Audio Volume Control > Configuration tab > Built-in Audio - Profile: Analog Stereo Duplex`

Answer (score 3):

This does not seem to be directly related, but I had success by installing the `skypeforlinux-64.deb` file that can be downloaded from https://skype.com.

The snap version of skype didn't work correctly. Neither input nor output worked.