# Broken sound in Skype (Version 8.26.0.70) after Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, skype

After upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 version, Skype became unusable. The audio quality during the calls sounds robotic, although other program sounds remained ok.

How to solve this issue? Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Download latest directly from Skype.com.  V. 8.27.x.x worked flawlessly with my dell xps...  The repository  and snap packages didn't work for me or were older.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785338/skype-audio-not-working-in-16-04) to posts similar to my own, the problem seems to converge to "Latency". So I installed "PulseAudio Control" and change the "Latency Offset" in the tab "Output Devices - Advanced". I added +20 ms. This was the ideal value.

Now the sounds during the calls are clear.